# Draw outline around custom polygon shape?

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

CSS - how to make border for custom shape in css so that the border is ONLY on the outer edges of my shape (not as it is now in the inside)?

I am using div with :before and :after pseudoclass...

https://codepen.io/RobotHabanera/pen/oGqwez

This is CSS :

```
  .nosce {
        box-sizing:border-box;
        position:relative;
        left:100px;
        top:100px;
        margin:0 auto;
        width:850px;
        height:570px;
        background:orangered; 
        border: dashed 2px #000;



    }

    .nosce:before {
        content:'';
        position:absolute;
        z-index:2;
        left:-57px;
        top:536px;
        width:545px;
        height:260px;
        background:orangered; 
        border: dashed 2px #000;          
    }

    .nosce:after {
        content:'';
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        left:203px;
        bottom:-285px;
        width:285px;
        height:30px;
        background:orangered;
        border: dashed 2px #000;
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use SVG to create this shape.

Comment: svg is a new concept for me...so I will need to learn svs first :) but of course it is no problem only takes time

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tyy4p67L/)

Comment: For infos :Where mix-blend-mode is implemented, it could be used in some cases https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aLYGww / https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SVG` is the recommended way to create such shapes. It offers simplicity and scale-ability.

We can use `SVG`'s `polygon` or `path` element to create a shape like above and stroke / fill it with some solid color, gradient or a pattern.

Only one attribute `points` is used to define shapes in `polygon` element. This attribute consists of a list of points. Each point must have 2 numbers, an x coordinate and a y coordinate. A straight line is drawn automatically from the last point to the starting point to close the shape.

Below is the necessary code to create this shape:

```
<polygon points="55,5 55,450 5,450 5,820 260,820 260,850
                 550,850 550,570 855,570 855,5 55,5"
         fill="orangered" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="8,4" />
```

Below is a brief description of the above code:

- `points` attribute defines the structure of the shape.
- `stroke` attribute defines the color for the outline / border.
- `stroke-width` defines the thickness of the outline / border.
- `stroke-dasharray` attribute controls the pattern of dashes and gaps used to stroke paths.
- `fill` attribute defines the color for the interior shape to be filled.

**Output Image:**

[image: polygon shape]

**Working Example:**

```css
svg {
  height: auto;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="900" height="855" viewBox="0 0 900 855">
  <polygon points="55,5 55,450 5,450 5,820 260,820 260,850 550,850 550,570 855,570 855,5 55,5" fill="orangered" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="8,4" />
</svg>
```

**Useful Resources:**

Below are some useful links for SVG:

- [Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)

Comment: how did you convert my codepen into shape in your answer -> did you use any SVG generator ?

Comment: No. I didn't use any tool for this. Its all hand written code. Once you know the basics of SVG; its not very difficult :)